# fetching score per term in a specific field

Tags: lucene

I'm currently using the snapshot version on lucene 4.0 (because of bm25), I was wondering on a possibility of getting the score for a given term.
For e.g., on the index I store two fields per document, namely the content of a document in contents field and authors in authors field.
Now, when I retrieve the documents, I fetch authors as well, but when I fetch authors, I would live to get the scores per each author (collection wide score), so that I can have a sort of ranking of authors.

I.e., is it possible that after fetching authors, to query lucene for each author and this way to find its respective score (I'm relying on the BM25 scoring model)? Is yes, is this the best way to do so?

thanks a lot

Comment: :), I didn't know I had to do that, now certainly I did. 
well, I couldn't fund much help from the link you sent, I did already have a look at it before posting though

Comment: @Nik: Do you mean you want the number of times a term occurs in a corpus? I'm not sure what it means for the author to have a score - usually documents are the ones with scorees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explain() if you are just debugging.

Otherwise, if you really need 'sub-scores' or 'scores for only a portion of the query', simply run that part of the query by itself, or if thats not fast enough, walk the Scorer hierarchy using Scorer.getChildren() in your Collector, saving references to the subscorers you care about.

Then in your collectors collect() you could capture those subscores too.